# R - How to create multiple scatterplots from dataframe

Tags: r, plot, graphics, dataframe, scatter-plot

I have a data frame below

```
     dw.05.art.rel.ch dw.10.art.rel.ch dw.15.art.rel.ch dw.20.art.rel.ch dw.25.art.rel.ch dw.30.art.rel.ch dw.35.art.rel.ch dw.40.art.rel.ch
0.25       2.14751794        1.3573794         1.378441        1.0225707         1.250907        1.3704892         1.018457        1.1266434
0.5        0.06980416        1.5074681         1.618793        1.3340371         1.153321        1.1491761         1.015098        1.0486423
0.75      -0.53753859        0.5501804         1.215985        1.1780073         1.276440        1.1058739         1.128350        0.9961578
1.00      -0.28508794        0.4966175         1.049642        0.9306377         1.008549        0.9741328         1.037897        0.9515636
     dw.45.art.rel.ch dw.50.art.rel.ch
0.25        1.0668396        1.0484025
0.5         1.0080182        1.0074631
0.75        0.9927887        0.9398075
1.00        0.9711958        1.0396354
```

I'd like to create multiple scatterplots from a single dataframe. The values in each row (e.g., 0.25) being the Y values and plotted against X values that are the numbers in the column name (e.g., "dw.05.art.rel.ch" is 5). Attached is an example I made in excel. I'm stuck on how to create the X values and how to generate multiple plots. 
[image]

Comment: `matplot(seq(ncol(dd)) * 5, t(dd), type = 'l')` or `plot(c(5, 40), c(0, max(dd)), type = 'n'); for (ii in 1:nrow(dd)) lines(seq(ncol(dd)) * 5, unlist(dd[ii, ]), col = ii)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `ggplot2`. First, let's "melt" the data from wide to long format and extract the x values from the column names. Assuming your data frame is called `dat`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

dat.m = dat %>% 
    add_rownames("group") %>%
    melt(id.var="group") %>%
    mutate(x = as.numeric(substr(variable, 4,5)))
```

All lines on a single graph:

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x, value, colour=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw()
```

Multiple panels:

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x, value)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ group) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw()
```

And here's what the graphs look like:

[image]

[image]

You can also create a separate graph for each value of `group`: The code below will save all the graphs (one for each value of `group`) in a list called `pl`. You can print them to the console, save them as pdf files, etc.

```
pl = sapply(sort(unique(dat.m$group)), function(i) {
  ggplot(dat.m[dat.m$group==i, ], aes(x, value)) +
    facet_wrap(~ group) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    theme_bw()
}, simplify=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your case is quite simple since the column names are regular. Assuming your data frame is called df:

```
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  plot(as.numeric(substr(names(df), 4, 5)),df[i,])
}
```

This will make all the plots with basic formatting.

Or

```
matplot(seq(ncol(df)) * 5, t(df), type = 'l')
```

Or

```
plot(c(5, 40), c(0, max(df)), type = 'n')
for (ii in 1:nrow(df))
  lines(seq(ncol(df)) * 5, unlist(df[ii, ]), col = ii)
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "dw.05.art.rel.ch dw.10.art.rel.ch dw.15.art.rel.ch dw.20.art.rel.ch dw.25.art.rel.ch dw.30.art.rel.ch dw.35.art.rel.ch dw.40.art.rel.ch
0.25       2.14751794        1.3573794         1.378441        1.0225707         1.250907        1.3704892         1.018457        1.1266434
0.5        0.06980416        1.5074681         1.618793        1.3340371         1.153321        1.1491761         1.015098        1.0486423
0.75      -0.53753859        0.5501804         1.215985        1.1780073         1.276440        1.1058739         1.128350        0.9961578
1.00      -0.28508794        0.4966175         1.049642        0.9306377         1.008549        0.9741328         1.037897        0.9515636")
```

Comment: this actually does work, dont know why the downvote, someone must be in a bad mood or it was just hadley passing by